# How to show images from database in a rdlc report in a windows form application

Tags: c#, windows, forms, rdlc

In a windows form application i am trying to show images from database in a rdlc report. In the database i have stored the image path and in rdlc report i have used image with source as "database" and MIME type as "image/png" but after running the report is show red cross signed images instead of original images.
[image]

I have verified the images path, and also in windows forms the images are showing correctly with the exact same path.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting image source as "Database" i have set it to "`External`" and also enabled `_reportViewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;` and used `file:///` before the image path and it worked for me.